# remove catalog search box which is present left to normal search box

Tags: catalogsearch

here : "CATALOG SEARCH BOX" is displaying. please help me to remove it

I want to remove "CATALOG SEARCH BOX" which is left to normal search box,

I dont want to delete normal "SEARCH BOX".

please help to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the following from the template (mind that it is present two times, maybe just delete both occurrences):

```
<div class="input_cat">
    <select name="cat" class="cat-search">
        <?php echo Mage::helper('rainbowsettings')->getCategoriesCustomSearch($category,$curId);?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,

you are genius,

i removed it only once in that file. 

but it is present 2 times....

now i removed 2 times....

problem solved. thanks a lot for your support.